# If I click a link I want to get QUERY STRING of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').attr('onclick', 'window.location.href=hideref(this.href); return false;');
    function hideref(strUrl){
    return "https://test.xyz/?q="+escape(strUrl);
    }
    </script>
```

This is my code
If I click

`<a href="https://example.com/post/1">link 1</a>`

Then it will be like

```
https://test.xyz/?q=https%3A//example.com/post/1
```

But I want it to be like

```
https://test.xyz/?q=/post/1
```

How can I make this?

Comment: You should not be using attr to set an event listener

Comment: Also /post/1 is not the query string. A querystring is what is after the ?

Comment: oh, sorry then how can i call that /post/1 thing in english?

Comment: `/post/1` is the path of the url (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `this.href` to send the url to the `hideref` function, you should use `this.pathname` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)).

Your code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function() {
      window.location.href = hideref(this.pathname + this.search);
      return false;
    });
    function hideref(strUrl){
        return "https://test.xyz/?q="+escape(strUrl);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! this works well!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, if it helped you, you can mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: If i wanna send things like /wpwp/wp.php?q=ddddddd how can i change this.pathname

Comment: I've updated the code, you need to add `this.search` so that you get both the pathname and the query string in your result.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to remove setting an `onclick` attribute through `attr()`. That's terrible practice.

Comment: I've updated the code so that it uses the jQuery `click` method as Rory suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- assign the click handler
- preventDefault to stop the link
- get the pathname and search
- encode it

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  var newUrl = "https://test.xyz/?q="+encodeURIComponent(this.pathname+this.search); 
  console.log(newUrl); // delete this and uncomment next line
  // window.location=newUrl;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://example.com/post/1">link 1</a>
<a href="https://example.com/post/1?bla=bla1">link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the pathname from the url, than reference the pathname from the anchor you clicked. You should also not be using attributes to define click handler.

```js
$('a').on('click', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  var path = hideref(this.pathname);
  console.log(path);
  //window.location.href = path;
});

function hideref(strUrl) {
  return "https://example.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(strUrl);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/post/1">link 1</a>
```